# How to pool the connections of mongodb with casbah?

Tags: scala, mongodb, connection-pooling, casbah

I'm using mongodb with scala driver `casbah`. If I'm not understanding wrong, it doesn't provide connection pool. Is there any pool libraries for casbah, like `dbcp`/`c3p0` for jdbc connections?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Casbah wraps the MongoDB Java Driver which provides a connection pool. An Instance of MongoConnection is actually an instance of the pool, not an individual connection. The pool can be tuned with an instance of the MongoOptions class passed to a new MongoConnection.

Comment: A reference would be nice.