# How to use Cashbah MongoDB connections?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, database

Note: I realise [there is a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359456/how-to-pool-the-connections-of-mongodb-with-casbah) but it talks about an old version of Casbah, plus, the behaviour explained in the answer is not what I see!

I was under the impression that Casbah's MongoClient handled connection pooling. However, doing lsof on my process I see a big and growing number of mongodb connections, which makes me doubt this pooling actually exists.

Basically, this is what I'm doing:

```
class MongodbDataStore {
  val mongoClient = MongoClient("host",27017)("database")

  var getObject1(): Object1 = {
    val collection = mongoClient("object1Collection")
    ...
  }

  var getObject2(): Object2 = {
    val collection = mongoClient("object2Collection")
    ...
  }
}
```

So, I never close MongoClient.

Should I be closing it after every query? Implement my own pooling? What then?

Thank you

Comment: So you tried to use `MongoOptions`, as was suggested in that question? Any sample code to reproduce the fact that connection pooling does not [work with this customization]?

Comment: Please do not continue to [delete previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081647/usage-pattern-of-casbah-mongodb-connections) and then ask them again like this.

Answer (score 7):

Casbah is a wrapper around the MongoDB Java client, so the connection is actually managed by it.

According to the Java driver documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/) :

> If you are using in a web serving environment, for example, you should
>   create a single MongoClient instance, and you can use it in every
>   request. The MongoClient object maintains an internal pool of
>   connections to the database (default maximum pool size of 100). For
>   every request to the DB (find, insert, etc) the Java thread will
>   obtain a connection from the pool, execute the operation, and release
>   the connection. This means the connection (socket) used may be
>   different each time.

By the way, that's what I've experienced in production. I did not see any problem with this.

Comment: Do you have any explanation as to why I get "SocketException: Too many open files" after my app is running for a while. And doing lsof I see way more than the 100 connections...?

Comment: Are you sure that you are reusing the same MongoClient object? Can it be that you're creating multiple ones?